# What are the mathematics journals focus on computational research article in number theory or algebra?

Tags: article-writing, computational-number-theory

I know $\text{Mathematics of Computation(AMS)}$ is journal aiming research articles consisting of lots of computations.

But this is one of the highest journals in this area to my knowledge.

Is there other similar type journals ranking lower than the above $\text{Math. Computaion}$  journal which gives priority the `computational` research articles in `Algebraic Number Theory` or in `Algebra` etc ?

Comment: Typically the way someone beginning research in mathematics discovers what types of articles are published in certain journals is from browsing in mathematical department reading rooms (or the library; or tables of contents of journals on the internet), from bibliographies in the papers on which the research is based, by looking at the journals that certain authors in your area publish in (visit their homepages), etc. Maybe you could provide more context to explain why this doesn't work in your specific case.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, It is ok as you said. Specially as you said in which journals the authors in my area published/publishing their papers, it is nice suggestion. But if you go the home page of $\text{Math. computation}$ journal,it says, it focuses on high quality computational papers. My question is in that respect. Which are the other such journals in number theory or  algebra ?

Comment: I don't know much of anything about this area or I would have listed some journals. If you have access to [Mathematical Reviews](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet) (I don't), that might be a good place to begin. Just click on the authors, journals, etc. that come up when you search for papers you know about, and you'll be led down a lot of rabbit holes (some of which are essentially bottomless).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro,thank you very much